# Daily consumption delta based on purchase dates

Tags: mysql, sql, tableau-api

I need to make a (Tableau) daily graph depicting consumption dynamics against previous day grouped by those clients who increased consumption, decreased consumption, and net change overall. Sample is below.

Calculation logic for sample: for every day for every client calculate difference vs previous day for that client, sum those above 0, sum those below 0, sum total. 
[image]

The sample was made manually from a relatively small data set. 
The real table has over 2 mil rows, and is not very consistent in that clients start buying at different days, may skip various periods buying nothing. 
Initial table structure is like that:

```
client_id   date    sales
    1   2018-09-01  4
    1   2018-09-02  5
    1   2018-09-04  3
    2   2018-09-1   2
    2   2018-09-2   2
```

While calculating table difference per date is simple, calculating pure growth and pure churn is hard, because the date row is not continuous for all clients.
I thought of adding the delta_to_previous column to each row when loading the initial dataset from the data storage, like:

```
WITH orders AS (
    SELECT client_id,
           date,
           SUM(sales) as sales
    FROM dwh_orders
    GROUP BY client_id, date
)
SELECT
    client_id, 
    date, 
    sales,
    LAG(sales, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY client_id
        ORDER BY date
    ) as prev_date_order_value,
    sales - LAG(sales, 1) OVER (
        PARTITION BY client_id
        ORDER BY date
    ) as prev_date_order_delta
FROM 
    orders;
```

Then for each date I can just show sum of positive values, negative values, total.

Problem, this approach will show consumption change at the next date of purchase, and if client buys 5 items on March 1 and then 5 on May 1, there will be no change for him at all. What it should do is show -5 for March 2 and +5 for May 1.

I am a bit puzzled at the optimal approach to this. The general solution could also use some review probably.

If someone dealt with a similar problem, I could really use your advice. 
If you are experienced with sql, I could use your advice on how to convert the initial dataset (see sample above) into something like

```
client_id   date    sales delta
    1   2018-09-01  4   0
    1   2018-09-02  5   1
    1   2018-09-03  0   -5
    1   2018-09-04  3   3
    2   2018-09-1   2   0
    2   2018-09-2   2   0
```

If you know a bit about Tableau, I could use help on building graphs like this using its tools.

Comment: do you want every day in the result? can you summarize what it is you are asking for? it isn't clear. plus: are you using MySQL 8 or an earlier version?

Comment: @Used_By_Already I do not need every day, Tableau can build continuous axis between end point. I do need days on which there were no trips, but there were yesterday. MySQL 8, yes. I guess I am not sure about most efficient approach to this thing. Trying to make a pass over each day for 3 years now, with every day sales joined via full join with sales from yesterday, but so far it looks like that will take 8 hrs to calculate this way. Could be there is an easy way I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
with cdates as (
      select client_id, min(date) as dte, max(date) as maxd
      from dwh_orders
      group by client_id
      union all
      select client_id, dateadd(day, 1, dte), maxd
      from cdates
      where dte < maxd
     ),
     cd as (
      select client_id, date, sum(sales) as sales
      from dwh_orders
      group by client_id, date
    )
select cdates.client_id, cdates.date,
       coalesce(sales, 0) as sales,
       (coalesce(sales, 0) -
        lag(coalesce(sales, 0)) over (partition by cdates.client_id order by cdates.date
       ) as delta
from cdates left join
     cd
     on cdates.client_id = cd.client_id and
        cdates.date = cd.date
option (maxrecursion 0);
```